# sample result after rollup func

Tags: promql, victoriametrics

If i have a metrics which step is 60 seconds, I want a result which have one point per 120 seconds, and every points is sum of before two points,

for example
(t1=t, v1), (t2 = t+60, v2), (t3 = t + 120, v3), (t4 = t+180, v4), (t5 = t+240, v5), (t6=t+300, v6)
I want result(t2 = t+60, v2+v1) ,(t4 = t+180, v4+v3), (t6 = t+300, v6+v5)

If I use promql like
sum_*over_time(metric[2m]),

I will get (t1=t, v1+v0), (t2 = t+60, v2+v1), (t3 = t + 120, v3+v2), (t4 = t+180, v4+v3), (t5 = t+240, v5+v4), (t6=t+300, v6+v5)

I must sample the result  with 120 second  after sum_over*_time , how should I write promql?

Comment: Why to you insist in using promql for this? It seems liky you already have a result you need, and all what's left is to simply filter out "odd" data points. You can use something like `step=120s` for this (or Min step 2m if you use this in Grafana)

Comment: @markalex is right, the amount of produced datapoints in response depends on the `step` param, which is natively set by visualization tools like Grafana or vmui. So when sending your query just add GET param `step=2m`
You can read more about query_range API here https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#range-query